# Stuck on DE question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

currently stuck on this question. I think it's a reduction of order question but the solution isn't given, or am I missing something?

$x^2y'' + 2xy' - 2y = 18x^4$ given that $y(x)$ is finite as $x -> 0$ and $y(1) = 0$

Comment: Use $y = xv(x)$ for reduction of order in the homogeneous problem.

Comment: @Mattos cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Euler DE. You either try $y=x^m$ to find the basis solution for the homogeneous DE or you can substitute $x=e^t$ to transform into a linear DE with constant coefficients and use standard solution methods via exponentials.

Comment: That makes things much easier.